# Is it possible to find out if a value exists twice in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an integer arraylist..

```
ArrayList <Integer> portList = new ArrayList();
```

I need to check if a specific integer has already been entered twice. Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Not without iterating the `ArrayList`

Comment: Try entering the items into a structure that forces uniqueness like Set.  Or keep the items sorted when you add items and search for items next to each other.

Comment: What makes you think that "it will be too hard to do that", just iterate over `ArrayList` and compare it with others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### My solution

```
public static boolean moreThanOnce(ArrayList<Integer> list, int searched) 
{
    int numCount = 0;

    for (int thisNum : list) {
        if (thisNum == searched) 
            numCount++;
    }
    
    return numCount > 1;
}
```

Comment: If you add `if(numCount > 1) return true;` to the loop, you will potentionally save many iterations, but will get the same result.
You can also add a `.contains` check before the loop for the case, that the element is not present in the list.

Answer (score 22):

You could use something like this to see how many times a specific value is there:

```
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(portList, 1));
// There can be whatever Integer, and I use 1, so you can understand
```

And to check if a specific value is there more than once you could use something like this:

```
if ( (Collections.frequency(portList, x)) > 1 ){
    System.out.println(x + " is in portList more than once ");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will tell you if you have at least two same values in your `ArrayList`:

```
int first = portList.indexOf(someIntValue);
int last  = portList.lastIndexOf(someIntValue);
if (first != -1 && first != last) {
    // someIntValue exists more than once in the list (not sure how many times though)
}
```

If you *really* want to know how many duplicates of a given value you have, you need to iterate through the entire array. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Will return a list of all indexes where the given value
 * exists in the given array. The list will be empty if the
 * given value does not exist at all.
 *
 * @param List<E> list
 * @param E value
 * @return List<Integer>    a list of indexes in the list
 */
public <E> List<Integer> collectFrequency(List<E> list, E value) {
   ArrayList<Integer> freqIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   E item;
   for (int i=0, len=list.size(); i<len; i++) {
       item = list.get(i);
       if ((item == value) || (null != item && item.equals(value))) {
           freqIndex.add(i);
       }
   }
   return freqIndex;
}

if (!collectFrequency(portList, someIntValue).size() > 1) {
    // Duplicate value
}
```

Or using the [already availble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) method:

```
if (Collections.frequency(portList, someIntValue) > 1) {
    // Duplicate value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to do this in one method, then no. However, you could do it in two steps if you need to simply find out if it exists ***at least more than once*** in the List. You could do

```
int first = list.indexOf(object)
int second = list.lastIndexOf(object)
// Don't forget to also check to see if either are -1, the value does not exist at all.
if (first == second) {
    // No Duplicates of object appear in the list
} else {
    // Duplicate exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set portSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
portSet.addAll(portList);
boolean listContainsDuplicates = portSet.size() != portList.size();
```

Comment: How is that going to detect duplicates? If `portList` is not empty, `portSet` is going to be changed and `addAll` will return `true` regardless of whether there are duplicates.

Comment: Yup, I realized I was an idiot as soon as I said it, Shame on the two  who upvoted me (and... well... me too).

Comment: Much improved. Now it behaves as advertised. It could be a one-liner: `boolean listContainsDuplicates = portList.size() == new HashSet<Integer>(portList).size()`. However, I think OP wants to know something different: whether a specific value already exists twice, not whether _any_ value is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following solution to find out whether an ArrayList contains a number more than once. This solution comes very close to [the one listed by user3690146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177897/is-it-possible-to-find-out-if-a-value-exists-twice-in-an-arraylist/23948103#23948103), but it does not use a helper variable at all. After running it, you get "The number is listed more than once" as a return message.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        list.add(4);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(8);

        int number = 8;

        if (NumberMoreThenOnceInArray(list, number)) {
            System.out.println("The number is listed more than once");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number is not listed more than once");
        }
    }

    public static boolean NumberMoreThenOnceInArray(ArrayList<Integer> list, int whichNumber) {

        int numberCounter = 0;

        for (int number : list) {
            if (number == whichNumber) {
                numberCounter++;
            }
        }

        if (numberCounter > 1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (in [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))):

```
    // getItemsMoreThan(list, 2) -> [4.45, 333.45, 1.1, 4.45, 333.45, 2.05, 4.45, 333.45, 2.05, 4.45] -> {4.45=4, 333.45=3}
    // getItemsMoreThan(list, 1)->  [4.45, 333.45, 1.1, 4.45, 333.45, 2.05, 4.45, 333.45, 2.05, 4.45] -> {4.45=4, 333.45=3, 2.05=2}
    fun getItemsMoreThan(list: List<Any>, moreThan: Int): Map<Any, Int> {
        val mapNumbersByElement: Map<Any, Int> = getHowOftenItemsInList(list)
        val findItem = mapNumbersByElement.filter { it.value > moreThan }
        return findItem
    }

    // Return(map) how often an items is list.
    // E.g.: [16.44, 200.00, 200.00, 33.33, 200.00, 0.00] -> {16.44=1, 200.00=3, 33.33=1, 0.00=1}
    fun getHowOftenItemsInList(list: List<Any>): Map<Any, Int> {
        val mapNumbersByItem = list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
        return mapNumbersByItem
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

By looking at the question, we need to find out whether a **value exists twice** in an ArrayList. So I believe that we can **reduce the overhead** of "going through the entire list just to check whether the value only exists twice" by doing the simple check below.

```
public boolean moreThanOneMatch(int number, ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int num : list) {
        if (num == number) {
            count ++ ;
            if (count == 2) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This question already answered many times and also has an accepted answer. Try answering some latest questions.